# bind, apply и call в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, backbone.js

Работаю с *Яндекс.Картами* на *backbon*-е и в коллекции получаю голые объекты дилеров (не модели).

Когда я вызываю в `initialize` коллекции `ymaps.ready(this.initMap)` в `initMap` создается новый объект карты, но так получается, что мне необходимо вызывать `this.initMap.bind(this);`

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, почему, если я использую `call` или `apply`, вместо `bind` выкидываются ошибки о том, что `ymaps.Map` это не функция. Вот код:

```
App.Collections.Dealers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Dealers, //Это класс модели
    initialize: function () {
        ymaps.ready(this.initMap.bind(this)); //тут если заменить на call(this) или apply(this) - ymaps.Map is not a function
    },
    initMap: function () {
        this.vwMap = new ymaps.Map('ymap', {
            center: [55.76, 37.64],
            zoom: 7,
            controls: ['zoomControl']
        });
        this.trigger('mapLoaded'); //На это не обращаем внимания..
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `bind()` возвращает обёрнутую функцию с контекстом переданным в аргументе. То есть это примерно вот так вот происходит (если очень сильно упростить полифилл), за некоторыми [недомолвками](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(context) {
    return function() {
        return func.apply(context, arguments);
    };
}
```

Методы `call()` и `apply()` же сразу вызывают функцию с переданным им контекстом.

В этом-то и проблема. `ready()` принимает [аргументом](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/ready-docpage/) функцию. Используя `call()` и `apply()`, Вы передадите результат выполнения функции, что и приводит к появлению ошибки.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все понятно.